# parceljs : how to merge files?

Tags: parceljs

Is it possible to merge JS files (or CSS files) with parcel ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="/js/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/club.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run

```
parcel build js.html
```

I got 2 minified .js files into /dist

Is there a way to get one single file ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's currently a config-driven way to get [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) to do this, but if your project can tolerate using modules (and if you have a choice - i.e. you wrote both `aos.js` and `club.js`), I would highly recommend this to avoid bugs that can come with global variables), then you can have your html reference a single `index.js` file, which then imports all of it's dependencies, like this:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="/js/index.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the `type="module"` property in the script tag - see [documentation](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/#%3Cscript-type%3D%22module%22%3E)

***js/index.js***

```js
import "js/aos.js"
import "js/club.js"
```